# Expandable list view expanding with switch

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an expandable list view wich i am trying to open with switch that is located in every "main line" in my view.
First I disable expanding exp list ivew with :

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            //Nothing here ever fires

            return true;
        }
    });
```

And here is the xml of the main view of exp list view:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="@color/White"

    >

    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:paddingLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="new text"
        android:id="@+id/tW"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        />

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textOff="Off"
        android:textOn="On"
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Then i custom adapter for exp list view in getGroupView implement on checked change listener like this:

```
final ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView) parent;
    mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                elv.expandGroup(groupPosition);
            }
            else{
                elv.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem is, let's say i have 6 "main views" and in each of them is one Text view and switch. At first it looks like evrything is working fine but after couple of minutes a realized that those switches aren't working as they should. For example i change the switch in first line and the group will expand but it will also change the  state of switch in some other line but will not expand it's group.
Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: try debugging with printing label text in onCheckedChange method to check that it is calling from proper parent?